# Add form field to com_content in Joomla2.5

Tags: joomla

Can someone help me figure out why this isn't working. It's actually group="content" plugin. I followed examples that I barely found on internet, but it was not enough. Following code was claimed to work but it does not for me.

Here is my onContentPrepareForm

function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data) {
    echo "working aroptimizer ";

```
if (!($form instanceof JForm)) {
    $this->_subject->setError('JERROR_NOT_A_FORM');
    return false;
}

// Check we are manipulating a valid form.
if (!in_array($form->getName(), array('com_contact.article'))) {
    return true;
}
// Add the fields to the form.
JForm::addFormPath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc');
$form->loadFile('arform', false);

return TRUE;
}
```

and in inc/arform.xml I have following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
<fields name="aroptimizer">
<fieldset name="ar"
label="AR Optimizer">
<field name="ar" type="list" label="Audience Match" description="Select your audience">
<option value="1">JSELECT</option>
<option value="1">DEPT_SALES</option>
<option value="2">DEPT_SUPPORT</option>
<option value="3">DEPT_BILLING</option>
<option value="4">DEPT_OTHER</option>
</field>
</fieldset>
</fields>
</form>
```

Goal for the above code is just to display form fields. All I wanna do is show some form fields to com_content(?option=com_content) page.

Thank You.

Comment: Is the function in the plugin called at all?

Comment: yes it does. I have an echo statement(for test) that shows up every time.

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress. Basically, field name "aroptimizer" does not exist on com_content, therefore, it was not able to render it.  I changed it to .

Secondly, following rule was never returned true. I will look into it later on. I've commented it out for now.

```
if (!in_array($form->getName(), array('com_contact.article'))) {
    return true;
}
```

I know I am unable to provide enough information here, but that is all I know for now. For further information, visit following link: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/joomla-dev-general/UP8X-slm98E/discussion